# Error Occured in SVN Repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, ankhsvn

While accessing `SVN` repository via a browser the error occurred after entering username and password. Below is the error

```
Redirect Cycle detected for URL http://localhost/svn/repos
```

Please help me. I am new user and don't have any idea about it.

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2012? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely a server misconfiguration issue than a client one. Further details on your configuration should shed light on the root of the issue: to know server version, client version and to see config files etc would be helpful.